# PAT testing of extension leads and RCD protected sockets (UK - industrial type environment)

Tags: safety

Not 100% sure this question belongs here, it was a choice between this stack and the home improvement stack but I have posted it here as it's about electrics in an industrial environment.

In an industrial environment where an extension lead is plugged into an RCD protected socket, is it still required to be PAT tested? It's in the UK so the relevant UK regs will apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RCD may prevent electrocution due to a faulty extension lead but [PAT testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_appliance_testing) involves many more things than just checking leakage currents. For instance, if live and neutral were swapped in the extension lead, an RCD would still trip and protect a person but, PAT testing and inspection requires that live and neutral are correctly wired to the correct points on the extension lead outlet.

So no, the use of an RCD is not a replacement for PAT testing.

From the wiki link above: -

> ***Testing involves a visual inspection of the equipment and any flexible cables for good condition, and also where required, verification of earthing (grounding) continuity, and a test of the soundness of insulation between the current carrying parts, and any exposed metal that may be touched.***

Answer (score 1):

We did PAT testing for our site and had to do the training to be qualified to do so.

Simple answer is "Anything that gets plugged in to a socket needs to be tested".

Then all the building wiring, rcds, mcbs, elcbs etc needs testing.

I was one of the several who kepth the database of the results for every item.
And items that failed were inspected, then repaired or destroyed as needed.